# Webpack: Ignore React Native Module and Load Web Module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I need to figure out how to alias a different package for a specific webpack configuration. The problem I'm trying to solve is with the VictoryJS library. (https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/). I'm using React Native Web inside a React Native project so when I fire up the project on a device/emulator it works fine because it can reference the appropriate package 'victory-native' but when opening in the web view, it cannot use 'victory-native' it needs to use 'victory' or else the project will crash.

I believe what I need to do is create new webpack config that either aliases the web version for the web or include both versions but EXCLUDES the native version. How would I go about doing this in webpack config?

Answer (score 1):

Good question Kevin, you can achieve this by using `react-app-rewired` and adding a `config-overrides.js` to the root directory of your project.

Here's the file contents:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
// God bless this absolute gent
// https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-686158264

// used by react-app-rewired

module.exports = {
    webpack(config, env) {
        config.resolve.alias['victory-native'] = 'victory';

        return config;
    },
};
```

This URL https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-686158264 points to a very helpful comment that has a boilerplate `config-overrides.js` for `react-native-web`.